# If $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable, then $fg$ is Riemann Integrable (with a twist).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration, simple-functions

My question is, as stated in the title: how do I prove that if $f,g$ are Riemann integrable over the reals ($\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R})$), then $f \cdot g \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R})$. However, I have been asked to prove this by using the definition given in class, which is different than the standard definition one would encounter in most analysis courses/texts.

Note: Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ represent the simple functions. Thus, if $f \in  \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, then $f = \alpha_1 \chi_{I_1}+ ... +\alpha_n \chi_{I_n}$, where $I_1,...,I_n$ are the bounded intervals over $[a,b]$. Also given was (not sure if it is necessary):

$\int f = \alpha_1 \lambda(I_1)+...+\alpha_n \lambda(I_n)$, where $\lambda(I)=b-a$.

The definition is as follows:

$f \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R})$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $g,h \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$  such that $$g_{\varepsilon}\leq f \leq h_{\varepsilon}
$$
and 
$$\int (h_{\varepsilon}-g_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$$

I have no idea where to start. If additional information is needed to answer the question, please let me know. I don't entirely understand the definition so it is difficult to know whether I have provided enough info. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "are the bounded intervals over [a,b]" Where did $[a,b]$ come from? Why not just say $f$ is such a sum, where each interval is bounded? By the way, $g_\epsilon \le f \le h_\epsilon$ implies $f = 0$ outside of a bounded interval, so I think we'll be in the standard situation after all.

Comment: I put $[a,b]$ in there because it was in my notes. I'm not sure if it is necessary, but I personally had never heard of simple functions so I am not sure how they are normally defined.